# run worldwind on raspberry pi 3 or other cheap arm

Tags: java, raspberry-pi3, jogl, worldwind

i worked on wwj for desktop application, and i like to use that on raspberry or another cheap arm board;
i use jogl native for arm(armv6hf) but this make error and not working.
error message :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.media.opengl.GLException: Profiles [GL4bc, GL3bc, GL2, GLES1] not available on device null
at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:949)
at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:960)
at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.getMaxFixedFunc(GLProfile.java:713)
```

so please help me...i dont know what to do anymore.
if you do that tell me how?

Comment: Please run "java -jar jogamp-far.jar" and tell me what it displays. This JAR is inside this 7z archive: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/archive/jogamp-fat-all.7z

Comment: i run this jar file and get this error:    java.lang.InternalError: Available GLVersions not set for EGLGraphicsDevice[type .egl, v1.4.0, connection decon, unitID 0, handle 0x648cff48, owner true, NullToolkitLock[obj 0x16905e]]
 at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDeviceCritical(GLProfile.java:1952)
 at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDevice(GLProfile.java:1875)

Comment: I advise you to post a comment on the official JogAmp forum. As far as I remember, JOGL 2.3.2 has been tested on several versions of Raspberry Pi, including Raspberry Pi 2 B. You'll have to indicate which operating system you use.